# How to solve this issue with redux form? It shows syntax error

Tags: react-redux, react-native, redux-form, react-native-ios

We are going to use redux form for all our app's forms. The app may have 5 different forms for different purposes. The trouble with this first form is that it shows syntax error. But before implementing redux form it was worked with the same syntax. What is the problem with this code?

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Text, Image, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform,View} from "react-native";
import {
  Content,
  Form,
  Item,
  Input,
  Icon,
  Button,
  ListItem,
  Row,
  Col,
  Grid,
  Toast,
  Container,
  Left,
  Right,
  Body


} from "native-base";
import styles from "../styles/formstyle";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";

const required = value => (value ? undefined : "Required");
const maxLength = max => value => (value && value.length > max ? `Must be ${max} characters or less` : undefined);
const maxLength15 = maxLength(15);
const minLength = min => value => (value && value.length < min ? `Must be ${min} characters or more` : undefined);
const minLength8 = minLength(8);
const email = value =>
  value && !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(value) ? "Invalid email address" : undefined;
const alphaNumeric = value => (value && /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/i.test(value) ? "Only alphanumeric characters" : undefined);

class SigninScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    gesturesEnabled: false,
  };

  renderInput({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) {
    return (
      <Item style={styles.item}
       error={error && touched}
                >
                <Icon
                  active
                  name="mail"
                  style={styles.icon}
                />
                <Input
                {...input.name="email"}
ref={c => (this.textInput = c)}
                  placeholder="Email"
                  placeholderTextColor="#a4916d"
                  style={styles.input}
                />
              </Item>
                     <Item style={styles.item}  error={error && touched}>

                <Icon
                  active
                  name="lock"
                  style={styles.icon}
                />
                <Input
                  {...input.name="password"}
ref={c => (this.textInput = c)}

                  secureTextEntry={true}
                  placeholder="Password"
                  placeholderTextColor="#a4916d"
                  style={styles.input}
                />
              </Item>
    );
  }



    login() {
    if (this.props.valid) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Drawer");
    } else {
      Toast.show({
        text: "Enter Valid Username & password!",
        duration: 2000,
        position: "top",
        textStyle: { textAlign: "center" },
      });
    }
  }

  render() {


    return (
      <Image style={background.img} source={require("../img/cover.jpg")}>
          <Container  style={styles.content}>

              <Form>
        <Field name="email"

               validate={[email, required]} />
        <Field
          name="password"
          component={this.renderInput}
          validate={[alphaNumeric, minLength8, maxLength15, required]}

        />
      </Form>
            <ListItem
              style={styles.list}
            >
            <Left>
                    <Button
                      primary
                      full
                      style={{width:"90%"}}
                      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Signup")}
                    >

                      <Text style={{color: "#0dc49d"}}>fb</Text>
                    </Button>
                </Left>
                <Body/>
                <Right>
                    <Button
                      danger
                      full

                      onPress={() =>
                        this.props.navigation.navigate("Forgetpass")}
                    >

                      <Text style={{color: "#0dc49d"}}>google</Text>
                    </Button>
            </Right>
            </ListItem>
            <Button
              full
              style={{backgroundColor: "#0dc49d", width:"90%"}}
            onPress={() => this.login()}
            >
              <Text style={{color:"#ffffff"}}>Sign In</Text>
            </Button>
          </Container>

      </Image>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'test'
})(SigninScreen)
```

It says JSX elements must be wrapped an enclosing tag. Eslint shows the second  component inside the renderinput. I am using it with native-base. What can cause this error? Also, can you check please if the communication within renderinput and fields component is right? I am not sure that after solving the syntax error this code will work :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`renderInput` method is returning two different items. You need to wrap them into a single wrapped component like the error is saying.

**Example**

```
  renderInput({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Item style={styles.item} error={error && touched}>
          <Icon active name="mail" style={styles.icon} />
          <Input {...input.name="email"} ref={c => (this.textInput = c)} placeholder="Email" placeholderTextColor="#a4916d" style={styles.input} />
        </Item>
        <Item style={styles.item}  error={error && touched}>
          <Icon active name="lock" style={styles.icon} />
          <Input {...input.name="password"} ref={c => (this.textInput = c)} secureTextEntry={true} placeholder="Password" placeholderTextColor="#a4916d" style={styles.input} />
        </Item>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying :)  But will this  {...input.name="email"}  comunicate with <Field> ? I mean  will each <Field> know what to render? Because both Fields  include component={this.renderInput}

Comment: I don't know because I have never used redux-form. I'm just giving you the cause of your error. Mine was just an example of how you can solve it.